# OAuth 2 client credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, client, single-page-application, credentials, production-environment

people!

I'm struggling with building OAuth2 infrastructure in my apps and faced to a problem: where to store client credentials in runtime. 
Is there any best practices for delivering client creds to JS SPA for dev/prod environments? 
Or hardcode is the only way to make such things?

Comment: Alex, have you found my answer useful or is there some problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

There are [best practices for browser based applications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04). You cannot store client credentials in a browser - they would become public. You should use [Proof Key for Code Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) (PKCE) instead - creating a secret value that serves as a one time password.